# How to make 21?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

How do you make $21$ from the numbers $1$, $5$, $6$, and $7$?

- You can use the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, as well as brackets.
- You must use each number exactly once.
- You cannot juxtapose numbers (i.e., 1 and 5 cannot be used as 15).

Comment: I would answer, but I found [this link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070407212018AAhkuX7) from another site that asks the same question.

Comment: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism?cb=1

Comment: I thought the issue was with copying copyrighted material **verbatim, without permission or attribution**. I don't see plagiarism here.

Comment: I agree with @frodoskywalker - the premise of the puzzle is the same, but that doesn't mean the puzzle itself is plagiarised. We're not deleting all the Monty Hall, Green-Eyed Oracle and similar questions, after all

Comment: Yes, this is not plagiarism, but I think this question has to be deleted because you can easily answer it simply searching on Google.

Comment: I don't think that can be a criterion for deletion, I agree in spirit that we should not just be a dump of other sites, but what if someone comes up with a different answer

Comment: I don't think another answer can be find, with this four numbers..

Comment: I am not talking specifically about this question, but the very fact that googling gives you answers cannot be a criterion for deletion is my contention

Comment: If being able to Google a puzzle is reason for deletion, then probably the vast majority of questions on this site would have to be deleted.

Comment: Maybe I was too strict saying it has to be deleted, but If this question was mine, I would like to award someone who has really spent effort in finding a solution, and not who simply searched for it.

Comment: It seems there's a bit of confusion about what plagiarism actually is. To be clear: **plagiarism is a *verbatim* copy from another source without attribution.** If you flag as plagiarism and have found a source, for reproducibility, please include the link in your "other" flag. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If this is an acceptable question, here is the answer:

> $$\frac{6}{1-\frac{5}{7}}=21$$

This is a pretty well known problem that, while the math obviously works, is unintuitive enough that it is sometimes difficult to solve the first time you see it.

Answer (score 5):

Observe

> $1 = \frac{5}{7} + \frac{6}{21}$

and rearrange.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this question a long time ago and after struggling with it came up with this:

> $ \binom {6 + 1}{7 - 5}$

which is

> $\frac {7!}{2!5!}= \frac {7 \times 6}{2} = 21$